# Did any country ever suppress the value of money?

Tags: war, money

I am thinking of events such as massive disease, starvation of war, during which physical resources and manpower were so important that it did not make sense anymore to count them with money.

As a consequence, the governement would have suppress the count of money, or make it pointless by artificially increasing the sum of money hold by the governement.

This question is raised because on wikipedia article about the Tiger tank, where money seems to have importance in outstanding crisis. For example, you can often read that a Tiger tank, built in Nazi Germany engage in a total war, cost XX million Reichmarks.

I imagine such a decision could only have been made by an authoritatiran governement, but I am interesting in any example. Also, I would like to know if some special system was put in place to regain a plausible monetary system after the crisis.

Comment: It might help us to write an answer if you cite a few examples of the "_some studies I have read_".

Comment: Downvote for unreferenced citation ('studies have I have read"), and for the questions without research.   Referring to unreferenced sources is not history - at best it is pub conversation, but more frequently it is an invitation to ugly diatribe.

Comment: This rather depends on exactly what is meant by "suppress", and to a certain extent on the meaning of "money".  But there are a number of examples of countries that have effectively suppressed the value of their own money by inflating it to astronomic levels: Weimar Germany, Zimbabwe under Mugabwe, current Venezuela, &c.  Do these count?

Comment: Lacks basic familiarity with fundamental conceptions such as "value," "price," "inflation," "cash," "specie," necessary for the question to make sense.

Comment: @SamuelRussell That's really all inexcuasable. Except for the "value" part. Did you get this right? I know, people said that I didn't. Even heard rumours of accusations that even Karl Marx made some errors in that regard… ;)

Comment: I made edit about the unreferenced sources, but anyway they were not the important thing. I have done research and found that every time you want to speak money about a country at war, you can. But often, you find text discussing of resources of this country without invoking money as a parameter. So is money really an issue during wartime, or just a totem for economists who want to speak about the period?

Comment: @SamuelRussell Could you explain where these conceptions intervene? I know most of those conceptions (at least on a basic fashion), except for "specie"

Comment: Money is a conceptual article. Anything can act as money. Wood. Bicycles. Gold. Bytes. Paper.  Specie is a term for money as precious metals. When money loses value by debasement of specie or increase in cash supply it is called inflation. Governments habitually inflate or deflate money. Governments have encouraged or tolerated hyperinflation. Governments have suppressed the use of currencies (crypto, foreign, community bank). Almost every government uses inflation for politicised ends.

Comment: It seems like you want to ask “why were tigers bough in reichsmarks despite total war?”

Answer (score 4):

Yes, nearly every government suppresses the value of money – but the question as stated doesn't make any sense.

The most frequent way to suppress the value of money is [inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation).  Every government manipulates the value of their money. Premodern governments [debased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debasement) their coins to suppress the value of money. Of course they maintained the fiat value, but suppressed the intrinsic value of the coin.

Furthermore [Seigniorage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seigniorage) means that it is nearly always prudent for a government to count things in terms of money – government makes a profit off every unit of currency. This is part of the reason why inflation is a tax that nobody votes for.

Having said that, the question makes no sense. The definition of [money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money) is a medium of exchange. You ask:

> physical resources and manpower were so important that it did not make sense anymore to count them with money.
>
> As a consequence, the government would have suppress the count of money, or make it pointless by artificially increasing the sum of money hold by the government.

It cannot make no sense to count things with money; money is the way we count things. If a government were to suppress the value of money not only would they need to increase their tax rate to compensate for the lack of seigniorage, but they would have no way to tax – because they couldn't assess value, or collect value.

Since you don't reference the sources that you're viewing, it is impossible to discuss the assumptions present in those sources.

The only context in which these terms could potentially make sense is if the value of the goods and services being purchased were existential – if failing to engage in the transaction would result in the elimination of the government. In such cases the government will typically nationalize the resource. You allude to the [Tiger Tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_I). Wartime production is not an economic activity – it is an existential activity. It is common for governments to nationalize (in some form) wartime production. It isn't that they "suppress the value of money", it is that they direct production of goods and services detached from economic incentives. Economic transactions must balance the values of the participants – wartime transactions are valued by "if I lose, I cease to exist".

@PieterGeerkens has offered an *excellent* alternative example of economic transactions carried out when the government has no recourse to specie.  Marxist economists advocate abandoning money and substituting "exchange entitlements" (which are really just another word for oppression). But in money is the way that we establish, measure and communicate value.  Suppressing the value of money would involve suppressing the measurement and communication of value, and that can only be done outside the context of economic activity – doing so in a modern nation state seriously delegitimizes the state, and is generally considered only when there is no alternative.

Comment: It seems you mistook devaluation for inflation. The first is made by the government directly, the second is the market reaction to some events. So, inflation is NOT the way to suppress the money value.

Comment: Not sure I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's called *feudalism* and arose organically, rather than by government decree, over much of Western Europe following the fall of the Western Roman Empire.

One might think of it as a type of *quantitative easing*. With the precious metals of Europe mined out above the water line, yet the steady stream east of specie for silk and spices unabated, *money* became too valuable to tie up in banal transactions such as daily labour. In consequence, much of the economy transitions to use of the moderately fungible *one day's labour*, freeing up specie for commercial and international transactions.

Comment: Arguably, the didn't suppress the value of money.  They implemented food rent in the absence of species.  One could even argue that money is defined as the medium of exchange, so food was ersatz money.  Excellent answer, I am just plucking at the margins.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Not really food, or even general produce, though. Serfs farmed their own land, and owed so many (typically about 40) ***days labour*** each year to their *lord of the manor*, which both farmed the lord's own demesne land and served his household. Undoubtedly some barter also occurred in the villages and hamlets.

Comment: Excellent point - it would be interesting to examine further, but I think we enter into a morass of definitions - is the situation best served by modelling labor as currency ? (Food rent is the traditional model that I learned, but you are correct about limitations). Then we get to the distinction between owning the serf and owning the labor.  Good answer. Sparks further thought.  Far better than my jaded cynical kvetching.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Check out the 1581 Dutch [Act of Abjuration](https://www.age-of-the-sage.org/history/dutch_independence_1581.html) and particularly this: "*and whereas God did not create the people slaves to their prince, to obey his commands, whether right or wrong, but rather the prince for the sake of the subjects (without which he could be no prince), to govern them according to equity, to love and support them as a father his children or a shepherd his flock, and even at the hazard of life to defend and preserve them.*" Ring any bells?

Comment: 1581 is rather late - I was thinking about preconquest England or Russia.  Given that the question covers all of human history, all of the examples are equally relevant. Like I said, I didn't disagree with any of the elements of your answer - I was just looking for edges.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: But 1581 is the height of "*absolute monarchy*", and the act speaks of the  mutual obligation between ruler and subject: "*our land, which has been always governed according to their ancient privileges, which are expressed in the oath taken by the prince at his admission to the government; for most of the Provinces receive their prince upon certain conditions, which he swears to maintain, which, if the prince violates, he is no longer sovereign.*" The *shire moots* and *hundred moots*, and their continuance under Norman  rule, speak likewise.

Comment: Aren't the Dutch outliers ?  Despite it being my heritage, I haven't studied their monarchy.  Their economy was, as I recall distinctive, but that may be later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102475/discussion-between-pieter-geerkens-and-mark-c-wallace).